# Time complexity of bit reverse function in C

Tags: c, time-complexity

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int reverseBits(unsigned int num)
{
    unsigned int reverse_num = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(unsigned int) * 8; ++i)
    {   
        reverse_num = (reverse_num | (num & 1));
        num = num >> 1;
        if(i != (sizeof(unsigned int) * 8) - 1)
            reverse_num = reverse_num << 1;
    }   
    return reverse_num;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int num = 0;
    scanf("%u", &num);
    printf("bit reverse of %u is %u\n", num, reverseBits(num));
    return 0;
}
```

What is the time complexity of this bit reversing function, if we change the input size to uint_8/uint_16/uint64_t, the for loop runs for the size of the input * 8 times. This functions runs in a constant time for n inputs. so what is the time complexity of this function in big "O" notation?

Comment: Constant time is O(1).

Comment: Assume that `n` is the number of bits. The complexity is `O(n)`. O notation can be a bit tricky. `O(2n)` is still `O(n)`. Consider that a simple sort like bubble sort, shell short, etc. have a complexity of `O(n**2)`. So it's more about the largest term in the polynomial: If you had an algorithm that had complexity of: `O(3n**3 + 97*n**2 + 23n)`, the complexity would be `O(n**3)` because when `n` diverges, `O(n**3)` [eventually] swamps the other terms

Comment: Be aware there are two uses of complexity. One is theoretical, where every bit manipulation counts, and we care about the complexity of an algorithm as a function of the number of bits of its input. Another is practical, where we assume a computer with a fixed-word size and care about the complexity of an algorithm as a function of its input value(s) or other sizes, given that elementary operations on words perform in constant time. The latter ignores growth beyond the word size; it is only concerned with growth within the computer’s limits.

Comment: In any case, it is unusual to be concerned much about the complexity of bit-reversal. It is not an interesting problem theoretically, and the complexity is either O(*n*) if you have to reverse the bits yourself or O(1) if the processor has a built-in instruction for it. It is more common to be concerned with the actual performance of a bit-reversal function (such as wanting to optimize it for a specific processor). But you do not ask about that, so it is a bit puzzling why you ask.

Comment: I am concerned about the time complexity of the bit reverse function for this problem.

Comment: For strictly-compliant C code, `sizeof(unsigned int) * 8` should be `sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT`, along with `#include <limits.h>`  See [**5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types <limits.h>**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1).

Answer (score 0):

***O(n)*, for *n* bits.**

For `uint_8`, the algorithm runs in 8 steps.
For `uint_16`, the alrogithm runs in 16 steps.

etc.

---

I'm no expert, but some instructions sets might have a one-cycle bit reverse (use `__asm__`), so you can run in O(n) for n *bytes*; eight times faster. Some compilers might do this automgically if you use `-O3`.